# How to reverse words?

Tags: r, stringr

I need to be able to reverse words in R. For example convert "this is my text" to "text my is this". I tried to use word function from stringr package as below but didn't work and only got ""

```
word("this is my text", -1,1)
[1]  ""
```

Any suggestions why the above isn't working or any other way to reverse words?

Comment: Try `paste(rev(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]), collapse = ' ')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do an `strsplit` and then with `rev`

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(str1, "\\s+"), rev), collapse= ' ')
#[1] "text my is this"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "this is my text"
```